# How to filter the parent and its associated children from mat-tree angular material?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have created mat tree inside the drop down and reated input field to do the filter. The filter works, if i type the full text of parent/child name from the json. But, ***I want to do the filter while typing the character itself***. can find the sample code in stackblitz on below:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-tree-dropdown?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

**Anyone help will be Appreciated!!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use basic regexp for this case. Just change your filter function into like this:

```
public filter(filterText: string) {
    let filteredTreeData;
    if (filterText) {
      // Filter the tree
      function filter(array, text) {
        const getChildren = (result, object) => {
          var re = new RegExp(text, 'gi');
          if (object.item.match(re)) {
            result.push(object);
            return result;
          }
          if (Array.isArray(object.children)) {
            const children = object.children.reduce(getChildren, []);
            if (children.length) result.push({ ...object, children });
          }
          return result;
        };

        return array.reduce(getChildren, []);
      }

      filteredTreeData = filter(this.treeData, filterText);
    } else {
      // Return the initial tree
      filteredTreeData = this.treeData;
    }

    // Build the tree nodes from Json object. The result is a list of `TodoItemNode` with nested
    // file node as children.
    const data = filteredTreeData;
    // Notify the change.
    this.dataChange.next(data);
  }
```

Basically I've change the main filter conditional from this:

```
         if (object.item .toLowerCase() === text.toLowerCase() ) {
            result.push(object);
            return result;
          }
```

to this:

```
          var re = new RegExp(text, 'gi');
          if (object.item.match(re)) {
            result.push(object);
            return result;
          }
```

What it does is that instead of requiring to match the full text, using simple regex we can output elements that are partially matched.

You can see a [working StackBlitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-tree-dropdown-bcqbkk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: thanks for you replay. If i filter, for example a child "Banana", its associated child "Apple" also should come. I mean parents and its children also needs to be filtered

Comment: Have you checked the demo above? Not sure if I follow exactly what you just mean by now. As example above, when a user types in the parent, its associated children will show as it is a parent.

Comment: yes thats correct. But, if we type any child name, all the children under that particular parent should come. For example, If we type "Apple", we have to get "Fruit","Apple","Banana"

Comment: Ahh I see, you mean sibling of that child instead? Child is underneath it and sibling is besides it.

Comment: Just to note, your primary question is about: "I want to do the filter while typing the character itself.". So I think this should be stick to that

Comment: here If i select parent/second level child, I needs to bind only the third level children names in placeholder. I couldn't get solution only to bind third level. Can you tell me is it possible ?